# Tikz Colorbar meta min max problem

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Im trying to include a colorbar, where I encounter some strange behaviour.
The first Colorbar works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikzscale,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\newcommand\figurescale{1} 
\newlength\figH
\newlength\figW
\begin{document}
\centering
\setlength{\figH}{0.5\textheight}
\setlength{\figW}{0.9\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
width=\figW,
height=0.333\figH,
at={(0\figW,0.002\figH)},
hide axis,
scale only axis,                 
colorbar sampled,                
colormap/jet,
colorbar style={
    samples=100,                
    point meta min=295.1111, 
    point meta max=295.5111, 
    scaled y ticks = false,
    ytick={295.1111,295.5111},
   yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/.cd,precision=5},
}  
]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

but changing the `point meta max` from `295.5111` to `295.2111` and corresponding the `ytick` as

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikzscale,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\newcommand\figurescale{1} 
\newlength\figH
\newlength\figW
\begin{document}
\centering
\setlength{\figH}{0.5\textheight}
\setlength{\figW}{0.9\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
width=\figW,
height=0.333\figH,
at={(0\figW,0.002\figH)},
hide axis,
scale only axis,                 
colorbar sampled,                
colormap/jet,
colorbar style={
    samples=100,                
    point meta min=295.1111, 
    point meta max=295.2111, 
    scaled y ticks = false,
    ytick={295.1111,295.2111},
   yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/.cd,precision=5},
}  
]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

leads to the error

> Package pgfplots Error: the arguments of [mesh/rows=2,mesh/cols=75] assume 150 points, but I actually got N = 192 points! The data matrix appears to be incomplete or overcomplete!? [Use mesh/check=false to disable this message

Turning `mesh/check=false` does not help (it results in a corrupted Colorbar).

**Update**

I could get the Interval a bit smaller with this:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
hide axis,
scale only axis,
height=0pt,
width=0pt,
colorbar,
colormap/jet,
point meta min=295.1111,
point meta max=295.1121,
colorbar style={
    height=10cm,
    ytick={295.1111,295.1121},
    yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision=9},
}]
\addplot [draw=none] coordinates {(0,0)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But changing point meta max from 295.1121 to 295.1112

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
hide axis,
scale only axis,
height=0pt,
width=0pt,
colorbar,
colormap/jet,
point meta min=295.1111,
point meta max=295.1112,
colorbar style={
    height=10cm,
    ytick={295.1111,295.1112},
    yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision=9},
}]
\addplot [draw=none] coordinates {(0,0)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

gets the

> Dimension too large

error.  Is it possible to further decrease the displayed interval of the Colorbar? Is there a domain feature like in 
[pgfplots-error-dimension-too-large](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/365441/pgfplots-error-dimension-too-large) available for the colorbar?

I would like to change the meta max to about 295.11111112.

**Update 2**
Lualatex does not help here, it results in a corrupted colorbar:

[image: Lualatex working] [image: Lualatex not working]

Comment: Welcome! Could you please provide a complete [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) which also includes the definitions of `\figW` and `\figH`?

Comment: @marmot you will find now two mini examples in the question above

Comment: Thanks. Do you also get the warnings "Package pgfplots Warning: You have an axis with empty range (in direction y). R
eplacing it with a default range and clearing all plots. on input line 29." and "Package pgfplots Warning: Sorry, the colorbar is uninitialised - your axis has 
no color data. Consider using 'point meta=f(x)' or something like that. I am us
ing a color range of [0,1] for the colorbar. on input line 29."?

Comment: Yes, i get the same warning. But I only want to display the colorbar next to a picture, so i take the standard color range and only change the ytick of the colorbar to display the right values.

Comment: I see. Well, I guess that pgfplots is struggling to stretch the mini interval you provide to something reasonable. Do you really need so small distances? If yes, you can still with lualatex, which seems to do fine with the problematic code.

Comment: Actually I want to display very small deviation and it would be perfect, if I don't have to change the tex-engine as I don't know how the publisher would like that :P

Comment: Then think about compiling to PDF with LuaTeX locally and including the images in your document, so the publisher can use another engine. Don't know if fp would help here.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution to it. I just created a colorbar with a "standard" range from 0 to 1 and replaced the yticklabels with the correct labels. The final result looks like this 
[image: example]